# Now able to load html page in web view when trying to load it from internal storage of device

Tags: java, android, android-internal-storage

I have created an index.html inside a directory, named as "TestingPurpose", of my internal storage of device.

I was trying to load the html page which is inside internal storage of device, but not able to load it

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TestingPurpose/index.html";
webView.loadUrl(path);
```

But working if I try to load from assets directory

```
String path = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
webView.loadUrl(path);
```

How I can make the URL load in web view from the file which is inside the internal storage of device?

Comment: What is the value of `path` from your first example? You probably need to prepend `file://`.

Comment: Value of path is `/storage/emulated/0/TestingPurpose/index.html`. I have added prefix as you mentioned, but this time it's displaying `Webpage not available` and  `file:///storage/emulated/0/TestingPurpose/index.html` could not be loaded because: `net:ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TestingPurpose/index.html";
String url = "file://" + path;
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but still it's not working. I have added prefix as you mentioned, but this time it's displaying `Webpage not available` and  `file:///storage/emulated/0/TestingPurpose/index.html` could not be loaded because: `net:ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: Problem solved. Just add one more method of WebSettings Class i.e. `webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true)`; No need to add this if you are using `compileSdkVersion 29` and `targetSdkVersion 29`, but need to `setAllowFileAccess()` to `true` in `compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30`